# completely exit jquery function from function called from function

Tags: jquery, function, return

I expect this has been asked before but I have searched and cannot find the correct answer.

If a function is called, and while doing that function another is used to check something, how can the initial function be halted from the second function?

```
a(1);
function a(v){
    check(v);
    alert "value correct";
    // continue

}

function check(v){
    if ( v!=1 ){
        alert "stop here number wrong";
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options: pass up a return value or just `return` when you need to.

## Demo Using a Passed-Up Return Value

```js
a(1);
function a(v){
    var stopped = false;
    if (v==1){
      stopped = stop();
    }
    if (stopped) {
        return;
    }
    alert("did not stop");
}

function stop(){
    alert("I want it to stop here");
    return true;
}
```

## Demo With a Simple `Return`

Even simpler: just `return` when you call `stop()`:

```js
a(1);
function a(v){
    if (v==1){
        stop();
        return;
    }
    alert("did not stop");
}

function stop(){
    alert("I want it to stop here");
}
```

P.S. You can't do `alert "foo";` -- you need parentheses, like `alert("foo");`.

Comment: I've looked at your edits, but I'm not sure why my answer wouldn't work for you. Can you explain why it doesn't? Or, if it does, please remember to select an answer! :)

Comment: Hi, your code is good, but not what I'm looking for sorry, I'm trying to remove the IF from the initial function and only have it in the stop() function as I put in my second edit, as I will have several to check of different values, thanks again tho

Comment: @nathan Ah. Well, that's not possible. You can only `return` from one function at a time. You have to set some sort of `return` value or other state to check what happened in the `stop()` function. Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks ED, that's as I though.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
a(1);
function a(v){
   if (v == 1){ // don't do anything }
   else { /** DO SOMETHING **/ }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the function return when you want it to stop running

See comments in code below for changes:

```js
a(1);

function a(v) {

  if (v == 1) {
    // You may not even need this function
    // Just place a return 0; instead
    stop();

    // Have the parent function stop executing
    // As well as the child function
    return 0;
  }

  // Make sure to use parenthesis ()
  // When using "alert" function
  alert("did not stop");
}

function stop() {
  alert("I want it to stop here");
  return 0;
}
```